# Mapping an arc to a line segment while keeping the infinity

Tags: complex-analysis

The original problem is to map the complement of the arc $|z|=1, y\ge 0$ on the outside of the unit circle, so that the points at $\infty$ correspond to each other. (with a conformal map)

My idea is to map the arc to the line segment $|x|\le 1,y=0$, then use the function $w=z+\sqrt{z^2-1}$. Since the latter function keeps $\infty$, the former function also has to keep $\infty$. But this seems impossible: to map an arc to a line segment using a Mobius function, a point on the circle must be sent to $\infty$, so the original $\infty$ is sent to a finite point. A logarithmic function does the job, but it is not defined on $0$.

Am I in the wrong direction?

Comment: Trying to keep $\infty$ fixed at all stages makes it appear more difficult than it is. Map the complement of the arc to the unit disk, arrange it so that $\infty$ is mapped to $0$ and finish it in the obvious way.

Comment: @DanielFischer, How to map the complement to the unit disk? That doesn't seem to be a familiar function.

Comment: If it were not that arc, but the negative real axis, you'd know how, wouldn't you?

Comment: @DanielFischer, I think I know a way now. Arc to ray, $\infty$ to $i$, then take the square root. Now $\infty$ is $\sqrt{i}$ and arc is the real axis. Using some translation, reflection and zooming to make $\sqrt{i}$ to $-i$, and then line to circle. Now $\infty$ is taken to $0$.

Comment: Yes, that's it. You have some choice which automorphism (of the disk or half-plane) you use to get the image of $\infty$ into the origin, some give a bit nicer formulae than others, but that won't make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

The function that you are looking for can be obtained in a few steps.

For pedagogical purposes, I will first give a wrong solution below.

First, take the cross ratio $f_1(z) = (z,1,-1, -i)$. This maps the unit circle to the real axis. In particular, it maps the arc in question to the line segment $[0, 1]$. Also, it maps $\infty$ to $\frac{1+i}{2}$.

Then take $f_2(z) = z^4$. $f_2 \circ f_1$ maps the arc to $[0, 1]$ and $\infty$ to $-\frac{1}{4}$.

The rest is a translation moving $-\frac{1}{4}$ to 0, an inversion so that 0 becomes $\infty$, and another translation/scaling to take the line segment to [-1,1].

The problem with this solution is that with $z^4$, four points (so not only $\frac{1+i}{2}$) will be mapped to $-\frac{1}{4}$. This means there are three other points that are mapped to $\infty$ in the final result. So the correspondence to $\infty$ is not one-to-one. In each step, you want to have a function that is bijective.

Below is a right solution.

First, take a cross ratio (possibly with translation and scaling) to map the arc to [-1, 1], and $\infty$ to $a$ (which is certainly not on the real axis). Let us denote this function as $f_1(z)$.

Second, use the function $f_2(z) = z-\sqrt{z^2-1}$, where sign of the square root is uniquely determined by the condition $|f(z)| < 1$. Let $f(a) = b$.

Third, take $f_3(z) = \frac{b-z}{1-\bar{b}z}$. This is an automorphism of the unit disc that swaps 0 and $b$.

Finally, take $f_4(z) = \frac{1}{z}$. This function swaps the interior of the unit disc with the exterior, and maps 0 to $\infty$.

$f_4 \circ f_3 \circ f_2 \circ f_1$ is the desired mapping.